# How do I start ssh command en subsequently a local command in a script?

Tags: ssh, webcam, vlc

I often at home on the 2nd floor and I keep an eye on the (open) groundfloor gardendoors by webcam and these scripts.

First I connect to the remote system with **$sh ~/.camconn** which contains:

```
sshpass -f 'passw' ssh -X name@remoteip '~/webcam5050'
```

the remote file ~/webcam5050 contains:

> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> cvlc -vvv v4l2:// --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mjpg,vb=2000,width=320,height=240,venc=ffmpeg}:duplicate{dst=standard{access=http,mux=mpjpeg,dst=0.0.0.0:5050/video.mpjpeg}
> ```

After a 5 to 6 seconds wait, I start the local webcam viewer **$sh ~/compaqcam**, containing.:

```
cvlc http://remoteip:5050/video.mpjpeg
```

and bingo: I get a nice VLC window on the desktop.

Of course I would like this all to happen with one command and I tried without avail:

```
#!/bin/bash 
(camcon &) && (sleep 8 &) && (compaqcam &) &
```

A tiny bit of succes with I had with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
(sshpass -f 'passw' ssh -X name@remoteip '~/webcam5050'&) && (sleep 8 &) && (cvlc http://remoteip:5050/video.mpjpeg &) &
```

which at least does show "sshd (accepted)" on the remote, but then nothing further happens.

Can one point me in the right direction?
If so I would be very(!) gratefull since my bash manuals (4pcs) failed me in this case.

Comment: Why do you have an `&` after the `sleep 8` in the brackets. That's going to put it in the background, which is not want you want from a sleep command I'd expect. Also, why one line in the script -- you could just do it in separate lines (again, without the `&` after the sleep)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your setup but I suspect the issue is the & after the sleep, which is going to put it into the background so it'll complete immediately, I think your script can just be:

```
#!/bin/bash  
camcon &
sleep 8 
compaqcam &
```

You could still do it on one line without the `&` after your `sleep 8` but this way is clearer and easier to edit in the future.

Comment: Great, it works (for 99.9% !) That is, the 0,01% imperfection is that I have to start the process twice. The first time a terminal opens and asks for a password. Shutting this down an starting again connection is as expected (although the terminal is there again but I can close it) and the video is on my screen.

Comment: BTW sleep without the "&" returns: "sleep: invalid time interval `compaqcam'"

Comment: That's odd, if they're on separate lines in the script in shouldn't see that as a parameter, if you do it on one line with the brackets it should still work. For the password thing you need to look at how to give ssh permission to login to the remote machine automatically, I can't recall the commands to do it but the man page for ssh should help. You need to generate a key on the remote machine and then copy it to the local machine in the right place. I've only got limited access 'net access at the moment so I can't find the a good example, you should be able to google it.

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

camcon &
sleep 8
compaqcam &

did the trick, along with ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id.
Thanks a lot!